# Extending inner elements in WPF custom extension element

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I'm using [Xceed WPF Toolkit DateTimePicker](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/DateTimePicker) to have both date and time in one element:

```xml
<xctk:DateTimePicker x:Name="DTCalendar" Margin="10,10,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" ValueChanged="DTCalendar_ValueChanged" Width="234" Height="34" Format="Custom" FormatString="dd ddd yyyy, HH:mm" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></xctk:DateTimePicker>
```

However, my issue is that the TimePicker drop-down list is too short, height-wise:
https://i.imgur.com/nham5JG.png

Is there any way to extend it height to the max without editing the underlying source?

Comment: You could try defining your own template with a closer scope than that of the toolkit. https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/blob/master/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution/Src/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit/DateTimePicker/Themes/Generic.xaml

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time using WPF, how would I go about defining that?

Comment: Why is it too small? There is a scrollbar which allows the user to *scroll* to the desired value. I would advise you live with it. The answer is to modify the `DateTimePicker` style. Visual Studio still installs with `Blend for Visual Studio` which can help when editing a style in xaml. But that will take a significant learning curve. See [Modify the style of objects - Blend for Visual Studio | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/modify-the-style-of-objects-in-blend?view=vs-2022)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to set the `MaxDropDownHeight` property of the `TimePicker` element using an implicit `Style`:

```
<xctk:DateTimePicker x:Name="DTCalendar" Margin="10,10,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" ValueChanged="DTCalendar_ValueChanged" 
                     Width="234" Height="34" Format="Custom" FormatString="dd ddd yyyy, HH:mm" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" 
                     HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
    <xctk:DateTimePicker.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="xctk:TimePicker">
            <Setter Property="MaxDropDownHeight" Value="1000" />
        </Style>
    </xctk:DateTimePicker.Resources>
</xctk:DateTimePicker>
```

Comment: This works like a charm. Now all that is left is to understand why and how, to apply it myself next time. Thanks.